# How to get more user data in onesignal

Tags: javascript, web, onesignal

i find this [Data Collected by onesignal](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/docs/data-collected-by-the-onesignal-sdk) and i want to get the user country,Device OS,Device Model,Push Status.

i already read all onesignal [Web Push SDK](https://documentation.onesignal.com/v5.0/docs/web-push-sdk) but only find how to get the user id using this (javascript):

```
OneSignal.getUserId(function(userId){});
```

i only find how to get all the data using cURL with [this documentation](https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#view-device).

how to get the data using javascript like the getUserId

**Update**

cURL to get data do not give country data either

Answer (score 0):

The Tags are what you are looking for. OneSignal automatically creates these for most of the things you are looking for (browser, IP Address, Session Times)

```
OneSignal.push(["getTags", function(tags) {
    console.log("OneSignal getTags:");
    console.log(tags);
}]);
```

Comment: from this i only get the Tags from the user not the Device, Platform, and Country